# Зачитывать стихи

Tags: лексика, фразеология

Можно ли сказать: "зачитывала стихи"? Можно ли текст (любой) **за**читывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли текст (любой) зачитывать?

Да, такое значение у глагола "зачитать" есть.

Зачитать 
1. Офиц.
Прочитать вслух для всеобщего сведения; огласить. З. приказ, резолюцию.
(БТС, Кузнецов)

> Можно ли сказать: "зачитывала стихи"?

Сказать-то можно. Но с учетом смысловой нагрузки глагола "зачитать" вряд ли это будет понято правильно. Стихи в нормальном состоянии всё-таки читают, а не зачитывают.

Хотя, с дугой стороны, есть еще два значения у зачитать: истрепать многократным чтением и не вернуть взятое почитать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. На уроке говорят: 'Зачитайте строки из стихотворения, в котором то- то и то- то. . . '